# Asterisk dynamic Lua Dialplan

Tags: linux, lua, asterisk

I am using the Asterisk PBX_LUA.so module to create a Test Dialplan, but I am not able to create a dynamic Dialplan, is it possible?

I changed parts of the module sample to test:

```
extensions = {}
extensions["demo"] = {}

extensions["demo"]["s"] = demo_start;

extensions["demo"]["2"] = function(c, e)
    extensions.demo["1"] = function() demo_instruct() end --<<-- "it's possible?"
    app.background("demo-moreinfo")
    demo_instruct()
    end

extensions["demo"]["3"] = function (c, e)
    channel.LANGUAGE():set("fr") -- set the language to french
    demo_congrats()
    end 

extensions["demo"]["i"] = demo_invalid;
```

but when I type 2 and then 1, option 1 is not recognized and throws me to the extension ["i"] (invalid).

is it possible to do this with Asterisk Lua Dialplan?

Answer (score -1):

You should create ENOTHER context and use it.

You also can use X for any digit and check digit in LUA.